# How to run a applescript to enter a terminal command

Tags: command-line, terminal, applescript

I have been messing around with voice commands, but ran into a snag. I am trying to get a terminal command to run but it is not working. The command makes asterisks "snow" fall. 
This is what I have so far.

```
tell application "Terminal"
activate
run script "ruby -e 'C=`stty size`.scan(/\d+/)[1].to_i;S=["2743".to_i(16)].pack("U*");a={};puts "\033[2J";loop{a[rand(C)]=0;a.each{|x,o|;a[x]+=1;print "\033[#{o};#{x}H \033[#{a[x]};#{x}H#{S} \033[0;0H"};$stdout.flush;sleep 0.1}'"
end tell
```

All I get are errors

Answer (score 2):

Command line scripts executed with the `do shell script` command. The string escaping can get a bit gnarly, so be careful with that too. Here's a simple example:

```
do shell script "say \"Today is `php -r \"echo date('l');\"`\""
```

**EDIT:**

OK, I just realised your script actually depends on having a Terminal window to run in, so the usual approach of `do shell script` won't work here.

There are still a lot of unescaped quotation marks in your Applescript, but rather than fixing those, I think it would be easier to put the whole ruby script into a stand-alone file and pass that to Terminal instead.

**stars.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

C=`stty size`.scan(/\d+/)[1].to_i;
S=["2743".to_i(16)].pack("U*");
a={};
puts "\033[2J";
loop {
  a[rand(C)]=0;
  a.each {
    |x,o|;
    a[x]+=1;
    print "\033[#{o};#{x}H \033[#{a[x]};#{x}H#{S} \033[0;0H"
  };
  $stdout.flush;
  sleep 0.1
}
```

**AppleScript**

```
tell application "Terminal"
   activate
   do script "~/stars.rb"
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but for some reason the script I want to run is still giving me errors, but it runs fine in terminal.

Comment: I've edited my answer — please take a look and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Aha! And all this time I've been sending them to the Finder. Thanks for that — I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to escape a shell command for AppleScript is to save the command in a text file. Run the script below and copy the Result.

```
set myText to read (choose file) as «class utf8»
```